# An error when adding a user control to the project

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, combobox, visual-studio-2005

I created a UserControl in my project. After that I change it to be inherited from combobox instead of UserControl -

```
public partial class EprComboBoxControl : System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
```

**Then I build the project and that control appears in the tool box**. Then I created a new windows from and add the item from tool box. When I am adding the control it says an error as follows.

> failed to load the toolbox item 'EprComboBoxControl'.It will be removed from the tool box.

I am using VS 2005

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add application exe in  toolbox item.

Or

Create instance of control and use.

Please follow [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsmobiledev/thread/9df6e5b1-e814-4344-aafc-02327718d6d9) for more reference.